# The norm of real powers of strictly positive bounded linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

Why does one have $\|A^x\|=\|A\|^x$ if $A$ is a positive, linear, bounded operator and $x$ is a real number?

By spectral theorem I would deduce
$$\|A^x \|=\| {U^*}^x D^x U^x \|=\|D^x\|=\|D\|^x=\|A\|^x$$
for unitary matrices $U, U^*$ and some diagonal matrix $D$. Is that correct or in other words is ${U^*}^x$ still unitary?

Comment: By Spectral Theorem.

Comment: @Normal so is the following correct in the finite dimensional case? $ \| A^x \|=\|U^*^x D^x U^x\|=\|D^x\|=\|D\|^x=\|A\|^x $

Comment: I don't think you also have power to the $x$ for unitary matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer goes back to how we define $A^x$ in the first place. The decomposition $A=U^*DU$ leads to 
$$A^x = U^* D^x U \tag{1}$$
Property $(1)$ could just as well be a definition of $A^x$. To see why no powers on unitary factors are needed, compare $(1)$  with 
$$A^2 = U^* D UU^* D U = U^* D D U= U^* D^2 U$$

The unitary factors don't affect the operator norm, and the result $\|A^x\|=\|A\|^x$ follows... but only for $x\ge 0$.

For $x<0$ the statement is false: consider
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 2& 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
where $\|A\|=2$ and  $\|A^{-1}\|=1$.

Comment: You are of course right I got confused with the definition. thanks a lot!